# Laravel - Nginx 404 page on production on every exception

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, logging, laravel-5.8

I have no idea why in my staging server kept showing Nginx 404 Not Found where there is a crash

[image]

while locally, I can see perfectly fine

[image]

Even if it show 404 not found, I can go to the log file in Laravel

/storage/logs/laravel-*.log

I can see the crash stack trace... I've tried

`APP_DEBUG=true`, and `APP_DEBUG=false` show same result

What did I forget to do?

Comment: Have you cleared the cached config after changing `APP_DEBUG` in `.env` file?

Comment: Yes. I cleared the cache afer changed it.

Comment: it's a configuration in your server to let the application handle the error pages, you would have better responses in server fault

Comment: Also, in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx) there is an example of how to configure nginx

Comment: You said you cleared the cache, but did you clear the config cache too? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I did that also and it still not working.

Comment: What is the value of `APP_ENV`?

Comment: Have you checked your `Exceptions\Handler.php`? Seems like it does a redirect to a page after the crash, and the page is not found. I'm thinking about missing plugins (dev-only) or something like that

Comment: I would think this is caused by `APP_ENV` being set to `production`. You should change it to `staging` and see if that (along with `APP_DEBUG=true`) fixes the issue.

Comment: Also, you should check your Composer file, I am guessing you have Filp Whoops installed to display those messages (going from memory, but laravel 5.8 was a long time ago now) and if it's in `require-dev` it may not be installed on your production server, at least if you ran composer install with the `--no-dev` flag.

Comment: @code8888 any new result on this, sir?

Comment: My case is not production, but inside docker container on Ubuntu. Test case returned 200 OK but browser keep showing 404. The reason is nginx server doesn't have execute permission for www folder. So maybe you should consider checking folder's permission or nginx config file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **Nginx 404 error** will raise only when nginx (or any http server) couldn't find the page (the php page).

usually **php frameworks** doesn't allow the http servers to access each file and directory.

and they **Handle the Routing** themself with their router.

> if the **router** couldn't match any route, it would render the
> laravel's 404 page

The nginx pass all the urls to the router with the help of **Url Rewrite**

Url Rewrite can be handle in apache with apache configs or `.htaccess` file, but in case of Nginx,

In the case of any error in the Laravel:

- Error or Exception would arose
- The Laravel Exception handler catch the object.
- it will render the view (stack trace) view

## Inspections

so I think we have to check these error-prone places:

1. Nginx Url Rewrite Config
2. check the `.env` to have `APP_URL=[correct value]` & `APP_DEBUG=true` & `APP_ENVIOURMNT=staging` then `php artisan config:clear`
3. check if in `App\Exceptions\Handler` redirects to an non-existing page ( outside of laravel app) :

   - maybe something redirect to `localhost` & it is ok on your local, but in staging you have another domain.

among the above, I am more suspected with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything like this in your nginx or vhost configuration?

```
error_page  404              /404.html;
error_page  500              /500.html;
```

If so, you need to comment out this line.

This tells nginx to serve a custom static HTML file upon HTTP 404, or 500 error. And so the error is not rendered by PHP, and by Laravel, and so no pretty error. Still, the error is thrown by PHP, so you can see it in logs.

If you have something like this, try to comment it, reboot nginx, and try again. I think I remember having the exact same issue once, and this solved it for me.

Note that you can have other rules like this for other HTTP codes.